# How to authorise user for a web page in FB messenger, without logging in?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, facebook-messenger

I am building a chat bot in FB messenger that saves user profile data, food and calorie consumption. I am using Node/Express/MongoDB for the backend and want the user to be able to open a personal dashboard page inside the chat with a link. So that URL would be something like www.myapp.com/:id where :id is a personal key.

The problem I have is how can only the user belonging to this page and data open this without having to login? Normally you would go to a website, login and be able to see the page, but this not a step I want in a chat bot. I want the user just to open the page in the chat, whether that is results in opening a browser tab or a native webview. Any advice on how I can achieve this?

Comment: Depending on the sensitivity of the data, and duration of sessions on the "dashboard", you could dynamically create a temporary link with a somewhat short TTL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To verify if the user on the page is the facebook user you intend the page to be for, add [FB Messenger Extensions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webview/extensions) to the page.**

When clicking a webview in your bot, Messenger extensions will be able to tell who they are logged in as, and allow you to do whatever you want with that info. In your case, checking if the userid matches the one passed by your bot in the url. There are many ways to check this, like splitting query strings, but I stuck with the example route in your question.

Use the following on your dashboard page. The below will check with FB who the logged in user is, and if it doesn't match the ID of the link they followed, deny them access with a redirect.

```
<script>
    MessengerExtensions.getContext(<YOUR-APP-ID>, 
    function success(thread_context){
    // User ID was successfully obtained. 
        var psid = thread_context.psid;
        // Grab the user id from your url (assumes your url is /<USER_ID>)
        var loc = window.location.pathname.replace(/^\/|\/$/g, '');
        if (psid !=== loc) {
          window.location.replace("http://YOUR_DOMAIN.com/error")
        } 
    }, function error(err, errorMessage) {      
    // Error handling code
    });    
</script>
```

Docs on [getting user id with Messenger Extensions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webview/userid)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
Open Messenger, then open DevsConsole and go to Network tab. Now paste your link and click it. In the Network tab open the request details issued by the click. Under "Form Data" you should see this:

```
q:[{"user":<your_fb_id>,...
```

You can use this id to authenticate the user in your app - just couple it somehow with the authorized user in your app. This is just the first idea off the top of my head, it should be quite safe if you mix it e.g. with CORS security headers.

Comment: Can I find this setting here: https://developers.facebook.com/apps/ ? I can't find the option you mention. Thanks

Comment: Which option precisely you can't find?